# Could not create parent directory for lock file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.3.3-all/4295vidhdd9hd3gbjyw1xqxpo/gradle-7.3

Tags: build.gradle

Error show in MAC when I run my project. The error is:

```
Could not create parent directory for lock file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.3.3-all/4295vidhdd9hd3gbjyw1xqxpo/gradle-7.3
```

Mac when running a project, despite attempting to resolve it by removing **Gradle**, cleaning the project, and rebuilding it.  Unfortunately, you haven't provided the specific error message or details about your project, making it challenging to offer a precise solution.

Comment: Looks like Gradle does not have the necessary permissions... ensure that directory path `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.3.3-all/4295vidhdd9hd3gbjyw1xqxpo/gradle-7.3` exists and that Gradle has the required permissions to write to this location.